# Binary addition

Tags: c, bit-shift

I am trying to understand how Bitwise operators work in `C`, but I have an misunderstanding about the `<<` operator.

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Add(int x, int y);
int Add(int x, int y)
{
    while ( y != 0 )        /// Iterate till there is no carry
    {
        int carry = x & y;  /// carry now contains common set bits of x and y
        x = x ^ y;          /// Sum of bits of x and y where at least one of the bits is not set
        y = carry << 1;     /// Carry is shifted by one so that adding it to x gives the required sum
    }
    return x;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%d", Add( 13, 17 ) );
    return 0;
}
```

If I understand correctly works like this:

```
First Iteration:
|=======================================|
|                                       |
|   while ( y       !=      0     )     |
|   while ( 17      !=      0     )     |
|   while ( 10001   !=      00000 )     |
|                                       |
|   c       =   x       &   y;          |
|   1       =   13      &   17          |
|   00001   =   01101   &   10001       |
|                                       |
|   x       =   x       ^   y           |
|   28      =   13      ^   17          |
|   11100   =   01101   ^   10001       |
|                                       |
|   y       =   c      <<   1           |
|   17      =   1      <<   1           |
|   10001   =   00001  <<   00001       |
|   00010   =   00001  <<   00001       |
|                                       |
|=======================================|

Second Iteration:
|=======================================|
|                                       |
|   while ( y       !=      0     )     |
|   while ( 2       !=      0     )     |
|   while ( 00010   !=      00000 )     |
|                                       |
|   c       =   x       &   y;          |
|   0       =   28      &   2           |
|   00000   =   11100   &   00010       |
|                                       |
|   x       =   x       ^   y           |
|   30      =   28      ^   2           |
|   11110   =   11100   ^   00010       |
|                                       |
|   y       =   c      <<   1           |
|   2       =   0      <<   1           |
|   00010   =   00000  <<   00001       |
|   00000   =   00000  <<   00001       |
|                                       |
|=======================================|
```

Then `Y` becomes `0` and `X` returns `30`.

Now in the following code I have an issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int x = 13;
    int y = x << 1; /// 11010 = 01101 << 00001
    x = 0 << 1;     /// 00000 = 00000 << 00001

    printf("y = %d\n", y ); /// 26  | 11010
    printf("x = %d\n", x ); /// 26  | 11010
    return 0;
}
```

Here if I understand right we shift all bits one to the left:

```
int y = x << 1; /// 11010 = 01101 << 00001
```

But what exactly happens here:

```
x = 0 << 1;     /// 00000 = 00000 << 00001
```

Does `x` get cleared and filled with the rezult of `0 << 1` ?

Comment: What are bits in 0? 0s... what do you get if you shift 0s leftwards, and add 0s on the right? What is its value?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It is `0`, but I was not sure How works in this case.

Comment: `x = 0 << 1;` sets the variable `x` to the value of `0 << 1` which is 0. If you have a bunch of 0 bits and you shift them left by 1 bit, you still have a bunch of 0 bits. You're probably overthinking this.

Comment: why would it work any differently? BTW C says that for positive numbers, `x << y` equals `x * 2^y` (power, not xor) if it is a value representable in the type of the expression.

Comment: @lurker So this means that the representation of the First and Second Iteration is correct?

Comment: @MichaelB.: `x` is just assigned the value of the expression `0 << 1`. Your understanding of the first and second iterations is correct.

Comment: @P.W Thank you for that.

Comment: @MichaelB. Well-formatted post, btw.  thumbsup for the effort.

Comment: @P.W I was using `ddd` debugger to archive this results. Which is easier then `GDB` for me.

Comment: You can use this printbits function to visualize output: `void printbits(int x)
{
    for(int i=sizeof(x)<<3; i; i--){
        putchar('0'+((x>>(i-1))&1));
        if(i%8==0){
          printf("_");
        }
    }
  printf("\n");
}`

Comment: A simple assignment always ignores and discards the old value that was there before.  In fact, it's a little strange to even show the old value in your lines like `17 = 1 << 1`.  A compound assignment like `a += b` or `x ^= y` does use the old value.

Comment: @EsmaeelE I just need to type `p /t variable_name` in `ddd` and I get the desired binary representation. IF I call your function with `17` I get `0_00000000_00000000_00000000_0010001` instead of `00000000_00000000_00000000_00010001`

Comment: ok i cant correct first leading zero in my function but i think thats be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does x get cleared and filled with the rezult of 0 << 1 ?

`x` is just assigned the value of the expression `0 << 1`. Zero left or right shifted by any amount remains `0`.

> So this means that the representation of the First and Second Iteration is correct?

It is correct, except that substitution of the old values of variables (on the lhs) is a bit confusing as in the following cases.

```
17      =   1      <<   1 
10001   =   00001  <<   00001
```

and

```
2       =   0      <<   1
00010   =   00000  <<   00001
```

Instead depict it as:

```
y      =   1      <<   1 
y      =   00001  <<   00001
```

and

```
y       =   0      <<   1
y       =   00000  <<   00001
```

Comment: The values of `17      =   1      <<   1 
10001   =   00001  <<   00001` are only there to illustrate the binary representation of those Numbers.

Comment: @MichaelB.: Yes, I realized that. But it appears as if it is depicting that `lhs equals rhs`.

Comment: about that, but that was not my Intention :)

Answer (score 0):

`n << k` is actually `n * (2^k)` as long as you have enough bits available to keep all of the resulting bits. So `0 << k` is `0 * (2^k) = 0` whatever the (positive integer) value of k is.
Note that for usual 32 bit integers, a number on `p = 17` bits or more, like `65537 (0x0001_0001)`, will stop behaving like the multiplication once k is greater or equal to `(32+1)-p = (32+1)-17 = 16`, as for example `65537 << 16` is `0x1_0001_0000` which is using 33 bits and is truncated to `0x0001_0000 = 65536`.
With `65536 << 15` you may also start having strange results as the result, `0x1000_0000`, is changing the left most bit, which is the sign bit if you're not using unsigned values...